# Interacting with Android API Library?

Tags: android, api

I'm quite the beginner to programming in general (and esp. Java!), so I'm having trouble figuring out how to interact with the unofficial Android API library, shown here:

http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/

One of the snippets of example code say "see AppsResponse class definition for more info". However, how am I supposed to do this? There are two .jars provided, one of which corresponds to the Android Market API. Upon extraction with WinRAR (I'm on Windows, by the way), I go in a few folders deep and find a bunch of .class files. How do I open this to read, and figure out how to interact with the API? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can just look at it from the source?

http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/source/browse/trunk/AndroidMarketApi/src/com/gc/android/market/api/model/Market.java